# SQL Check Constrain with ONLY IF statment

Tags: sql-server, database-design, constraint

I have  a table with a check constraint that enforce a not null for the data column if the havedata column is true. is there away to modify the constraint to not allow case 3 to happen. i.e Data is not null Only if have data is true?

```
ID  HaveData   Data  
1      0       Null  
2      1       trg$%%D  
3      0       %^&&FFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an OR condition in your [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017).

Setup Table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CheckData ([ID] INT IDENTITY,
    [HaveData] BIT NOT NULL,
    [Data] NVARCHAR(25) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CK_HaveData_Data CHECK (([HaveData] = 0 AND [Data] IS NULL) OR ([HaveData] = 1 AND [Data] IS NOT NULL))
);
```

Add Data:

```
-- This works because Data is NULL and HaveData is 0
INSERT INTO CheckData ([HaveData], [Data])
VALUES (0, NULL)

-- This works because Data is not NULL and HaveData is 1
INSERT INTO CheckData ([HaveData], [Data])
VALUES (1, 'trg$%%D')

-- This fails because Data is not NULL and HaveData is 0
INSERT INTO CheckData ([HaveData], [Data])
VALUES (0, '%^&&FFF')
```

You can see this in action in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=26ebc5ceadbc69d7121fad72fd825df8).